I'm stuck at solving a limit that resembles the (1+n/1)^n
It's been 10+ years since my university days when I was actively solving limits, and today I promised that I will help out to solve a homework problem. However, I'm completely stuck on this one:
$$
\lim_{n->∞} \left(\frac{n^2 + 3n + 4}{n^2 - 5n + 12}\right)^{(\frac{n-1}{4})}
$$
Here is what I tried and failed:
Attempt 1) I've tried to find the roots of of polynomials, but both are not solvable under R.
Attempt 2) I've tried to introduce a substitution where:
$$
t=\frac{n-1}{4}
$$
This way I got a simpler expression, but I didn't know how to continue further.
Attempt 3) I've tried to take ln of both sides:
$$
ln(y) = \lim_{n->∞} ln \left(\frac{n^2 + 3n + 4}{n^2 - 5n + 12}\right)^{(\frac{n-1}{4})}
$$
which simplified to:
$$
ln(y) = \lim_{n->∞} {(\frac{n-1}{4})} * ln \left(\frac{n^2 + 3n + 4}{n^2 - 5n + 12}\right)
$$
then to:
$$
ln(y) = \lim_{n->∞} \frac{ln \left(\frac{n^2 + 3n + 4}{n^2 - 5n + 12}\right)}{\frac{4}{n-1}}
$$
where if I'm correct I can apply L'Hopital to get:
$$
ln(y) = \lim_{n->∞} \frac{\left(\frac{n^2 - 5n + 12}{n^2 + 3n + 4}\right)}{\frac{-4}{(n-1)^2}}
$$
but I got stuck.

Judging by the function graph in desmos, the solution seems to be approaching ~7.3, which is very close to $e^2$.
What am I missing? Do you have some tips where to continue looking?

Attempt 3 was the correct way to do it. But you computed incorrectly the derivative of $\ln ( fraction)$, since you didn't use the chain rule in a proper way. Multiplying by the derivative of the argument you get that the limit of $\ln y$ is 2. Hence the overall limit is indeed $e^2$.

The beginning of your 3rd attempt (before your miscalculation with L'Hopital) was promising. Next, use that as $x\to1$, $\ln x\sim x-1$ (i.e. $\frac{\ln x}{x-1}\to1$), so $\ln(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n-1}4\left(\frac{n^2 + 3n + 4}{n^2 - 5n + 12}-1\right)$.

Do you mean $(1+1/n)^n?$

Solved it with the input from @Crostul. Thank you! Thank you Anne as well, but I must admit that I don't yet understand your approach.

Heh, @ThomasAndrews. Yes!

More details on the fact that L'Hopital is overkill here (like in most cases, where peaople systematically rush to it). Replace it by: $\ln'(x)=\frac1x$, so $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\ln x}{x-1}=\ln'(1)=1$. Next, as $n\to\infty$, $a_n:=\frac{n^2 + 3n + 4}{n^2 - 5n + 12}\to1$. So, $\frac{n-1}4\ln a_n=\frac{n-1}4\frac{\ln a_n}{a_n-1}(a_n-1)$ has the same limit as $\frac{n-1}4(a_n-1)$. Finally, $\frac{n-1}4(a_n-1)=\frac{n-1}4\frac{8n-8}{n^2-5n+12}$ has the same limit as $\frac n4\frac{8n}{n^2}=2$.
